# What's the difference between the "cucumber" command and the "rake cucumber" command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command, cucumber, rake

What's the difference between the "cucumber" command and the "rake cucumber" command?

Is there some preference as to which should be used?  I think I heard calling "rake" is slightly slower...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the `rake cucumber` command first runs `rake db:test:prepare`, whereas just running `cucumber` does not (in which case you may get some unexpected results).